Searching the LaTeX Font Catalog for a specific Unicode character? (Second attempt)
Let me try again: Is there any way to search the LaTeX Font Catalog to find which fonts contain the specific character '⌘' (Unicode u+2318)? Any other ways to identify which fonts contain this character?
The suggestion to use albatross does not provide an answer to my question. While I didn't know about this command, and it's very useful, it does not provide a way to search the LaTeX Font Catalog for a specific Unicode character, which was the question. It only searches the fonts on the local machine.
This question is not a duplicate of Writing ॐ in latex, as that answer only involves the use of albatross, which does not search the LaTeX Font Catalog, as required in this question.
I'm only interested in searching The LaTeX Font Catalog. I've found other answer (which no longer work) involving other font catalogs, but this question is restricted to searching The LaTeX Font Catalog.
Thanks so much for any guidance or advice.
-Kevin

you can't. The catalog does not contain data about the unicode range covered by a font. In a full texlive most fonts mentioned in the catalog are installed on your machine, so the search result of albatross will cover a lot. But beside you will have to look at other resources. E.g. this lists fonts with this char: https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2318/fontsupport.htm.

you also need to define what you mean by which fonts contain this character? especially as you are asking about fonts that come with TeX rather than system opentype fonts. Most (nearly all) TeX fonts are not based on Unicode so they will not have a U+2318` character, but they may have a character that printed looks like ⌘  so you'd have to do a visual search for something that looks like something, which requires AI or a human or ....

... or use \cmdmac of menukeys package without worrying about the fonts.

or texdoc comprehensive (especially for the non-unicode fonts)?

@UlrikeFischer, Thanks! I didn't know that most of the fonts in the LaTeX Font Catalog were installed on my system with a full texlive install.

@KevinZembower You can use the --include-tex-fonts option of albatross to also search your installed tex fonts.

IMHO, albatross is still an answer to your: “Any other ways to identify which fonts contain this character?” And for: “Is there any way to search the LaTeX Font Catalog to find which fonts contain the specific character '⌘' (Unicode u+2318)?”, you also need only two additional steps: Before using albatross make sure, you've installed all the free fonts of the catalog. After using albatross compare the result with the fonts listed in the catalog.

@cabohah, yes, of course it's similar. I wrote both questions, and even linked to the first question from the second. For the rassons I stated in the question, I didn't get an answer.

Simply asking a question again is the wrong way to push another question. The natural reaction in such a case it, that the new question is closed as duplicate. Substantial improvement of the not answered question but be better. If you still need to push it, see How to "push" my question?. But I also explained above why this question IMHO is still not substantially different from “Writing ॐ in latex”.

what to do with this question? it is a duplicate of the OP's previous question. but that question is closed as a duplicate of a third question and I don't see that the OP's questions are duplicates of that one, even if the best answer to this pair is the best answer to that other question. to see why notice that you have to know a good deal about the relationship between the font catalogue and the fonts picked up by, say, texlive, in order to see why using albatross might reasonably approximate a search of the catalogue. is there an answer explaining that?
